# How to change color of a specific acitonbar item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to design an Actionbar (android version >=2.3 using support v7). I want the color of a specific button to be different from other buttons.

Is there any simple way to do this ? Example design below

[image]

Comment: Which app that uses this menu design?

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it from your `Activity Class`**

In the `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` just add these lines and do the necessary imports.

```
        android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#d44334")));
```

It works in support action bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could think off using `android:actionLayout` in your `<item>` declarartion, post a comment if this is not a goog approach for you

Answer (score 0):

I think, that menu is designed programmatically with Java code, instead of using XML menu item. [This post](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/06/how-to-change-background-color-of.html) might explains a lot about creating menu programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create xml which contains Button and set it to Menu Item

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/actionViewLayout"
   android:showAsAction="always"
   android:title="Title"
   android:actionLayout="@layout/your_xml_file"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/actionViewLayout"
   android:showAsAction="always"
   android:title="Title"
   com.myapp.app:actionLayout="@layout/your_xml_file"
/>
```

It is important that you use your package name instead of "android" if you are using the SupportActionbar. Also dont forget to add namespace to the XML.